# Filling buffer, passed as argument by address

Tags: c, file, pointers

I am having a problem with a rather simple task: I want tor ead a file in a function, which takes a pointer to a buffer as one of its arguments. In the function, the buffer should be filed with the file's contents and the contents will be used later on outside the function.

However, it displays not the right stuff inside `readFile()` and even more rubbish outside `readFile`. Furthermore, I would like to display the contents of the file in hex (%02x), but I dont know how. I am struggling with pointer stuff. Could you help me?

```
uint8_t *buffer;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    uint32_t i = 0;
    unsigned long fileLen;

    // Read file
    fileLen = readFile(argv[2], &buffer);
    printf("Buffer afterward: %s\n", &buffer);
} 
unsigned long readFile(char *fileName, uint8_t *buffer){
    unsigned long fileLen = 0;
    uint8_t i;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen (fileName, "r");  /* open the file for reading */ 

    if(file==NULL){
        printf("Error reading %c.\n", fileName);
    return 0;
    }
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    *buffer=malloc(fileLen+1);

    if(!buffer)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
            fclose(file);
            return;
    }
    fread(&buffer, fileLen, 1, file);

    printf("Source message (%s, %ld bytes):\n%s\n", fileName, fileLen, &buffer);
    puts("\n");
    fclose(file);

    return fileLen;
}
```

This is the output:

´Source message (bla, 16 bytes):
blablablub
1234
�   ſ�  ſUJZ�����

Buffer afterward: p`

if the contents of `bla` are:

`blablablub

 1234`

Comment: How is `buffer` defined in `main`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include it into code. Added it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to allocate your buffer inside the readFile function, then `buffer` is assumed to be passed by reference, and not by value. That is:

```
unsigned long readFile(char *fileName, uint8_t **buffer);
```

So when you alloc memory for it, you use `malloc()` and store the address got into `*buffer`, but in order to test if the allocation has succeed, you have to test `*buffer`, not `buffer`. That is:

```
if(!*buffer)
{
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
        fclose(file);
        return;
}
```

For the rest of the function, you will use `*buffer`, not `buffer`.

```
fread(*buffer, fileLen, 1, file);

printf("Source message (%s, %ld bytes):\n%s\n", fileName, fileLen, *buffer);
puts("\n");
fclose(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda confusing because you said `which takes a pointer to a buffer as one of its arguments` but then your not actually passing a pointer to a buffer but instead, passing a pointer to an integer (which is used as a pointer, effectively a double pointer).

Personally, I prefer doing allocation outside the read function so there is no transfer of ownership (making memory management easier). Something like:

```
unsigned long readFile(char *fileName, unsigned char *buffer, uint8_t bufferSize){

    // -- read at most x number of bytes (bufferSize) from the file to buffer

    // -- return number of bytes read
    return fileLen;
}
```

But to answer your question, its not that you're passing your pointer by value, the pointer should be correct, except that your printf statement is wrong. This: `printf("Buffer afterward: %s\n", &buffer);` should be something like: `printf("Buffer afterward: %s\n", (char*)buffer);`

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted your code a bit:

```
/**
 * in order to allocate the buffer inside the function you need
 * to pass the address to the pointer
 */
unsigned long readFile(char *fileName, uint8_t **buffer)
{
  unsigned long fileLen = 0;
  uint8_t i = 0;
  char* ch = NULL;
  /* open the file in binary mode to get exact content
     otherwise the fileLen will be wrong */ 
  FILE *file = fopen (fileName, "rb");  

  if (file==NULL)
  {
    perror(fileName);
    return 0;
  }
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
  fileLen=ftell(file);
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

  *buffer=malloc(fileLen+1);

  if(!*buffer)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
    fclose(file);
    return;
  }

  /* read into the buffer, note the * in front of the buffer */
  fread(*buffer, fileLen, 1, file);

  /* since you do not know what is in the buffer, the following printf is a bit
     risky, you cannot be sure that the buffer is terminated by a \0 
     printf("Source message (%s, %ld bytes):\n%s\n", fileName, fileLen, *buffer); */
  /* instead do something like this */
  printf( "Source nessage (%s, %ld bytes):", fileName, fileLen );
  for (ch = *buffer ; *ch < *buffer + fileLen; ++ch)
  {
    /* if you want the output in hex */
    printf( "%02X", *ch );
  }
  fclose(file);

  return fileLen;
}
```